# how to do a delete and modify function correctly

Tags: c

This code has several issues that are beyond my understanding.

First, no matter how hard I try, the variable `ok` doesn't get saved in the file, thus ruining the display. It is strange because other variables work, it is just that one that doesn't seem to be working, even if I change the order.

Also, the delete and modify functions aren't working, as well.

I tried everything, but nothing seems to be working.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

  
// Structure of the employee
struct emp {
    char name[50];
    char ok[50];
    int hr;
    int age;
    int id;
};

FILE *f;

emp* add(emp *e,int n){
    int i;
    char p;
    emp *t;
    int k;

    t=(emp*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    f=fopen("Data.txt","w");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       
        printf("\nEnter Name : ");

        scanf("%s",(t+i)->name);

        printf("\nEnter Departement: ");
        
        scanf("%s",&(t+i)->ok);
        
        printf("\nEnter Age : ");
        scanf("%d",&(t+i)->age);
  
        printf("\nEnter avearge hour of works(per week) : ");
        scanf("%d",&(t+i)->hr);
        // k = ( ( (t+i)->hr ) *40 );//40 is minimum wage for each hour of work
        // printf("Salary of The employe: %d\n",k);
  
        printf("\nEnter EMP-ID : ");
        scanf("%d",&(t+i)->id);

        fprintf(f,"%s\n%s\n%d\n%d\n%d\n",(t+i)->name,(t+i)->ok,(t+i)->age,(t+i)->hr,(t+i)->id);
    }
    fclose(f);

    return t;
}

void aff(emp *t,int n){
    
    int I;
    
    f=fopen("Data.txt","r");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if (f != NULL){
            fscanf(f,"%s",&(t+i)->name);

            fscanf(f,"%s",&(t+i)->ok);

            fscanf(f,"%d",&(t+i)->age);

            fscanf(f,"%d",&(t+i)->hr);

            fscanf(f,"%d",&(t+i)->id);
             
            printf("Name : %s\n",(t+i)->name);
            printf("departement : %s\n",(t+i)->ok);
            printf("Age : %d\n",(t+i)->age);
            printf("Hours : %d\n",(t+i)->hr);
            printf("ID : %d\n",(t+i)->id);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}

//emp* modf(emp *t,int n){
//  int i;
//  int k;
//  char nv[50];
//  printf("id of the entry you want to be modified" );
//  scanf("%d\n",&k);
//  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
//      if(k==(t+i)->id){
//          scanf("%s",&nv);
//          (t+i)->name=nv;
//      }
//  }
//  return t;
//}

//void del(emp *t,int n){
//  int i;
//  emp a;
//  int k;
//  printf("position of the entry you want to delete?");
//  scanf("%d",&a);
//  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
//      if (a == *(t+i)) {
//          for(i=k;i<n-1;i++){
//              *(t+i)=*(t+i+1);
//          }
//      }
//  }
//}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int c;
    emp e;
    emp *k;
    k=&e;
    
    int n;
    emp *t;
    t=&e;

    char p;

ka:
    printf("Welcome To The employe management Menu\n");
    printf("1.Add employes?\n");
    printf("2.show all employes?\n");
    printf("3.delete an entry?\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    switch (c){
    
        case 1:
            ed:
            printf("How many employes you want to add?\n");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            
            add(k,n);

            if(p=='y'){
                goto ed;    
            }
            else goto ka;
            break;

        case 2:
            aff(t,n);
            break;
                    
        case 3:
            del(t,n);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `&` with format spec `%s` in `scanf` functions.

Comment: Is this the format in which you see the code in your editor? I wouldn't understand _anything_ if I looked at code like this. Edit: Thanks Remy :-)

Comment: `emp *t;` won't compile with a C compiler. It should be `struct emp *t;`. The C compiler produces lots of warnings and errors. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Unrelated: `goto` going back is generally messing with the ability to follow the flow for people. Keep your `goto`s only going _forward_, or don't use them at all.

Comment: `t=(emp*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));` isn't allocating enough memory, `t = malloc(n *  sizeof *t);`

Comment: `p` is never initialized so `p=='y'` has undefined behavior

Comment: @mmo guy "I tried everything, " --> Try enabling all warnings and use a C compiler for C code.

Answer (score 0):

At least these issues:

**Wrong allocation size**  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72902679/how-to-do-a-delete-and-modify-function-correctly/72903660#comment128765230_72902679)

Avoid allocation errors.  Allocate to the size of the refenced object, not the type.

```
// t=(emp*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
t = malloc(sizeof t[0] * n);
```

Easier to code right, review and maintain.

**Uninitialized `p`** [@Craig Estey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72902679/how-to-do-a-delete-and-modify-function-correctly/72903660#comment128765652_72902679)

`f(p=='y')` is undefined behavior as `p` is uninitialized.

This hints that  OP is not compiling with all warnings enabled.  Save time - enable all warnings.

**`emp` not defined**

Perhaps OP is not using a C compiler, but a C++ one?

**`i` not defined in `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {`**

Is `int I;` the true code?

**Bad `"%s"`**

Without a *width*, `"%s"` is worse than `gets()`.  Use a *width* like `"%49s"`.